# I am sending the GET request to the flutter app from the express API but I am not getting any output

Tags: node.js, api, flutter, express, postman

I am sending the GET request to the flutter app from the express API but I am not getting any output in the flutter App. The API is working in the postman and I am getting the perfect output in the postman.

[image: Express API. I have used the cors package as well]

Please help

[image: Postman data from express api]

[image: I am not able to fetch the data in the flutter app]

```
  testing() async{

debugPrint("Hello");

http.Response response = await 
http.get("http://192.168.119.97:3000/api/cricketer");
debugPrint((response.body));

debugPrint("Hello hy");
}
Future getData() async {
http.Response response = await 
http.get("http://192.168.119.97:3000/api/cricketer");
debugPrint((response.body));
data = json.decode(response.body);
debugPrint(('$data'));
setState(() {
  userData = data["cricketers"];
  debugPrint("Hello ");
  debugPrint(('$userData'));
});
   }
```

Calling the Function:

```
 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
 getData();
 testing();
 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text("Cricketer Info"),
      backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
       ),
       body: ListView.builder(
       itemCount: userData == null ? 0 : userData.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
         return Card(
           child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
           child: Row(
             children: <Widget>[
              // CircleAvatar(
              //   backgroundImage: NetworkImage(userData[index][""]),
              // ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Text("${userData[index]["name"]}",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
       },
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

I have uploaded the code also. Please check and if possible help

Comment: Please use code and not pictures. Also attach the part of your code where you are calling the function, this is just the definition of the method.

Comment: I have added the code as well. Please check

Answer (score -1):

First, you have to JSON decode the body for print, json.decode() gives some misleading. You can use jsonDecode(result.body) from 'dart:convert' package . Here  I have attached some
example codes of login(Post request). After decoding you can use a data model and factory method to convert to a dart object.

[repo dart file that send post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whQG6.png)

[my data model with a factory method for decode json to dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDZro.png)